# search layers in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

There are a lots of layers in my projects. Previously I have renamed a layer with "system" and to that layer I have set visibility hidden. I want to show that layer again but I have to search manually by scrolling the layer palettes and I can do that. But I want to know just that is there find dialog box which can search layers by name etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Photoshop CS6 (v13) and CC (v14) both have the capacity to search layers via several different options right there on the Layer Panel itself.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: is this not available in cs4

Comment: No, it is not in CS4. CS6 was the first version to add layer searching.

Answer (score 1):

Solution to your problem is in **Photoshop CS6** where you can select layers by Type - Name - Attribute etc. like in above answer if you don't have latest version. Then i have tip for you i.e. i use to do very often manage your layers by **Grouping** related **layers** this helps a lot to apply some thing on a multiple layers. This even helps if you have layers in different groups. Better management smart and timely output. Below is the link for further help.

[Layer Groups](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/layers/layer-groups/)

Answer (score 1):

On PC: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

On Mac: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

In Photoshop CC 2020 this enables you to do a **Name search** in the Layers Tab.

[image: Name search]

Alternately, you can use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. The shortcut to bring the Global search function in photoshop. This function was added in Photoshop CC 2017.

[image]

*In previous versions of Photoshop (below Photoshop CC 2017), <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> was the keyboard shortcut for reapplying the last-used filter.*

Comment: This answer is a bit short. Try to explain what happens when you press that combination.

Comment: I tried this in Photoshop CC 2020 and it doesn't seem to work.